# sort/max for strings in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have data from a collection as shown below and trying to get the Date field (string) which embedded to _id field, sorted by reverse order(desc) but i failed to get what is expected.

```
> db.l.find().sort({"_id.Date":-1}).limit(5)
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/25/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/24/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/21/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "02/26/2017" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "02/25/2017" } }
```

If i insert one more document and expecting  output for the same command as "02/27/2017" since it was last inserted. but no luck.

```
> db.l.insert({_id : {"Date": "02/27/2017"}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })


> db.l.find().sort({"_id.Date":-1}).limit(6)
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/25/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/24/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "12/21/2016" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "02/27/2017" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "02/26/2017" } }
{ "_id" : { "Date" : "02/25/2017" } }
>
```

Note: Date format is in mm/dd/yyyy format

I really wonder why its showing wrong here. please help

Comment: You are storing your dates as strings. So the sorting process is lexicographical/alphabetical order. You should instead store your dates as JS Date objects.

Comment: @Blaze Yes i agree with you, but the data was already present and i'm trying to clean it up by keeping two months old data. Is there a way to get the stats of a coll like last modified apart from oplogs? since i'm not using oplog in this setup.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such method. You could however, convert the dates to Date object